# How to quickly watch security camera footage?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I have an IP camera which records 10s .AVI video clips and uploads to my FTP server once motion is detected. So at the end of the day, I have hundreds of small video clips on my FTP server.

I want to quickly fast-forward through them. I tried drag-dropping all videos into VLC, which is fine but it doesn't work well when I increase playback speed to more than 10x.

Is there a better way of viewing all of these videos at an increased playback rate?

Comment: If you load the clips into a video editor, you can swipe through the clips at any speed you want, though I don't see the value of playing a 10 second clip in less than a second.

Comment: My camera can't record and upload clips longer than 10 seconds. So 5minutes of action becomes 30 video clips.

Comment: In that case a video editor seems the right solution: copy all the clips in succession on to the time-line and swipe through the combined stream with the mouse.

Comment: You can probably stitch the videos together with `avconf` or `ffmpeg`.  Not sure of the exact options but it seems like something ffmpeg could do.

Comment: you can try to concatenate all files into single one. Since those are avi you can do following on linux `cat file1.avi file2.avi file3.avi > concat.avi` on windows you can do it using `type file1.avi file2.avi file3.avi > concat.avi` if the filenames have numbers and are sorted in your filesystem you can use `cat *.avi > concat.avi`

Comment: For formats other than .AVI, this page contains a few suggestions on how to concatenate video files.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/637074/how-to-merge-multiple-more-than-two-videos-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what operating system you're using, but if it is GNU/Linux or similar it's easy to do like this from the command line:

```
find /path/to/ftp/directory -name '*.avi' -exec ln -s -t /path/to/all_files_dir/ {} +
```

The `{}` and `+` may need to be escaped with `\\` in your shell.

This creates symbolic links to all the video files in a single directory called all_files_dir.

Then just do:

```
mplayer -fs -fps 100 /path/to/all_files_dir/*.avi
```

Press <kbd>enter</kbd> in mplayer to skip to the next recording.

You can also do this with saved images by opening the images using lximage-qt using the open directory feature. Then hold down the right arrow to quickly view all the images.